# How can I get a user to subscribe to a Pusher Channel based on the group they are in?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, channel, pusher

Each user is placed in a group, my site has 5 groups. I only want events in group X to be broadcast to clients who are in group X. How can I create channels like this and get the client to subscribe to them?

```
Pusher.logToConsole = true;

        var pusher = new Pusher('ec160cc0a1ca15e463f4', {
            cluster: 'eu',
            forceTLS: true
        });

        var channel = pusher.subscribe("{{Player::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first()->group_id}}");
        channel.bind('NewPurchase', function(data){
            window.alert('successful!');
        });
```

I create these custom groups in my backend just fine however

```php
public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return [Player::where('user_id', $this->product->seller_id)->first()->group_id];
    }
```

I keep getting a 'Class Player not found', perhaps because the php I have there doesn't seem to be read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Player` is a model, instantiate it via fully qualified name

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe("{{\App\Player::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first()->group_id}}");
```

```php
public function broadcastOn()
{
   return [App\Player::where('user_id', $this->product->seller_id)->first()->group_id];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"The broadcastOn method should return a channel or array of channels that the event should broadcast on. The channels should be instances of Channel, PrivateChannel, or PresenceChannel."

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe("{{Player::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first()->group_id}}");
```

So, if you are having problems with the Class, you could add the param to the event. It should look like this:

```
class YourEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $group_id;

    public function __construct($group_id)
    {
        $this->group_id= $group_id;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel($this->group_id);
    }
}
```

and call the event:

```
event(new YourEvent(Player::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first()->group_id));
```